# Can a non residential Indian go to Nepal without a visa?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, nepal

I'm going to Nepal on a camping trip, I live in Dubai and I have an Indian passport. Do I still need a visa to enter Nepal?

Answer (score 4):

According to [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external.php?ref=d975cfc59f5c0abd06d16e872198110b), the database used by airline staff, Indian nationals do not require a visa to enter Nepal, and even though you live in Dubai you still hold an Indian passport, which means you are fine. Although a note is made that handwritten passports are not permitted, and it should have six months validity upon arrival.

Comment: All of the handwritten passports expired many years ago, so that should not be an issue.

Comment: Can also enter by air and land with a voter ID card. Also Indians have freedom of movement to Nepal, they can live and work there.

Answer (score 0):

Indian National passport holders do not need any kind of Visa for Nepal. Also, For south Asian country Bhutan, Srilanka, Bangladesh, Maldives, Pakistan, and China the visa fee is free and they will get on arrival visa.